# 有一點　can only be used for bad things, but how about 一點？

Tags: grammar, mandarin

I've learned that 有一點 can only be used for negative things, such as 有一點累，　有一點不好吃　etc　but not 有一點漂亮，　有一點好。

But how about if I say only 一點？ Is that the same?

For example, are the following sentences valid?:

> 這個甜點只一點甜，不太甜的。
>
> This dessert is only a little bit sweet, not too much.
>
> 這本書一點有意思，可是那本書真有意思！　你看看！
>
> This book is a little interesting, but that one is really interesting! You should read it!

Comment: `这个甜点只有一点甜，不太甜的`，this is negative, but it is caused by `只有`, not `有一点`. When we say something `有一点意思` or `有点`<sub>儿</sub>`意思`, it actually means it is interesting.

Comment: why not mention 有点 （no 一）？＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂有点（副；动）／一点（数量） **［相同］** 都表示程度不高，都可以跟形容词或心理动词配合，但意思和用法都有区别，不能互换。 **［不同］**  **１。** 都可以和形容词＂大、小、多、少、高、矮、重、轻、长、短、早、晚＂等配合，表示超过不多，但在句中的位置不同：＂一点＂在形容词作补语，常用于表示比较：＂有点＂用在形容词前作状语：（１）我觉得这件衣服贵了一点。（有点✗）（２）我觉得这件衣服有点贵。（一点✗）（３）林红比我矮一点。（有点✗）（４）林红有点矮，打篮球不合适。（一点✗）（５）今天打球的人比前几天多了一点。（有点✗）（６）今天打球的人有点多，很难找场地。（一点✗） **２。** ＂有点＂还可以修饰消极意义的心理动词和形容词，作状语，表示性质状态的程度不高；＂一点＂没有这样的用法：○有点累 有点着急 有点伤心 有点脏（一点✗）○有点不开心 有点不舒服 有点不满意（一点✗）（１）报考南京大学还是中山大学？赵刚有点犹豫。（一点✗）（２）大家都有点累了，早点休息吧。（一点✗）（３）我觉得有点困，想睡觉。（一点✗）（４）刘明明今天好像有点不高兴。（一点✗） **３。** ＂一点＂可以用在积极意义或中性义的形容词之后作补语，表示性质状态有一些改变；＂有点＂没有着样的用法：（１）怎么大家都不笑啊？

Comment: （２）你太慢了，请你快一点。（有点✗）（３）菜很好吃，要是辣一点就更好了。（有点✗）（４）吃了药，我感觉舒服一点。（有点✗） **４。** ＂一点＂是数量短语，可以用在名词前作定语，表示少而不定的数量，还可以组成＂一点都不／没。。。＂的格式；＂有点＂是副词，没有这样的用法：（１）等今儿有朋友过来，我先去买一点水果。（有点✗）（２）没什么，吃一点药就好了。（有点✗）（３）这里没有一点节日的气氛。（有点✗）（４）几年过去了，他的坏脾气一点都没改。（有点✗）（５）工作了一天，可是一点都不累。（有点✗）（６）这件事我一点都不知道。（有点✗） **５。** ＂有点＂还是＂动＋量＂短语，相当于＂有一点＂，可以带宾语；＂一点＂没有这样的用法：（１）地上有点水，小心滑倒。（一点✗）（２）家里还有点菜，不用买了。（一点✗）

Comment: “农夫山泉，有点甜” A well-known Chinese commercial :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, people try to soften a negative assessment, or if you’re shy, downplay the intensity of your response. 
“The dish was too salty!” vs “The dish was a bit salty.”
“It’s too noisy, let’s get out of here!” vs “It’s a bit noisy in here, shall we go elsewhere?”
As you can see, no matter the language spoken, it’s not what you say but how you say it that matters.

“有一點” serves this purpose in colloquial Chinese. I can’t imagine this phrase would be used in a professional or formal Chinese setting. It’s meant to downplay the intensity of your response.

To answer your question, it’s not necessarily the case that this phrase is used to denote a negative connotation.

“還不錯” 、”還可以” are other phrases used to downplay intensity of response. These are used to denote “is ok”. 
Example: 這本書還不錯，那本書很有意思！

I understand you were looking to highlight usage of “有一點”, but for your other example regarding desserts, I would favour something closer to:
這道點心不是很甜。
The tone is more assertive, appropriate for when you don’t care about offending the chef/dessert purchaser.

Answer (score 1):

Technically in oral, they have no difference, and we Chinese take 一點 as the abbreviation of 有一點.

"This book is a little interesting"="這本書有一點意思/有點意思/有意思".

"This book is little interesting"="這本書没一點意思/没意思". "没點意思" is unusually.

But "有一點 can only be used for negative things" that is incorrect.

In a scene, a boy asks "Do you like me?" to a girl, and the girl answers shyly. “你喜歡我嗎？” “有一點……” ⁄(⁄ ⁄ ⁄ω⁄ ⁄ ⁄)⁄ (OS: VERY MUCH!)

See? Not negative!

Answer (score 1):

“這本書一點有意思，可是那本書真有意思！　你看看！” is not valid, But you may say “這本書有一點意思，可是那本書真有意思！　你看看！” it is more Chinese

And 有一點 means not being positive when it is used with adj or VP. You are right.